# Passing Data in Datagrid between Two Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms say Form1 and Form2. I have two fields file name ,file path and a button which when clicked takes to Form 2 . Form 2 has a datagrid which has file name and file path and an OK button.If the row in Form1  already has file path and file name it should get populated in Form 2 and if i manipulate that data in Form2 and click Ok button, the data should be updated in form 1. Since i am new to C# i am finding this a bit difficult to do. Can you please provide me some pointers on how to tackle this problem

Answer (score 1):

The crude (and not recommended) way is to make the two data grid views 'Public'.  Then, when you exit a cell on one data grid you check to see if it's 'dirty', and if so process the update for both grids.  If one form is launched from the other, one update would read this.ParentForm.dgFileNames.Rows.... and the other would be this.frmSubordinate.dgFileNames.Rows...

A better approach is to have public methods on both forms, and invoke the other form's corresponding update method each time the rows on one grid are updated.

Realistically, each form should have user defined events for Adds and Updates defined that invoke the other form's methods.  This presumes both forms are always open in situations where updates will be entered in the grids.  This involves defining an interface and base class for the eventData that will be passed through the events.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily accomplish this using Form's Modal result.

Ideally your Form2 should be like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
private string _currentValue;

//Property to get value from Form1
public string CurrentValue
{
    get { return _currentValue; }
    set { _currentValue = value; }
}

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //set the dialog result to be as OK when button is clicked
    button1.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
}

public string getSelectedValue()
{ 
    return dataGridView1[<the field name you need to get>, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
}
}
```

In Form1, call it as:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.CurrentValue = <Your Value from Form1>;

If (form2.DialogResult() == DialogResult.OK)
{
textBox1.Text = form2.getSelectedValue();
}
```